# Non-Newtonian substance - Tahini

Tags: everyday-chemistry, food-chemistry

Raw Tahini seems to me like a non-Newtonian substance. When I mix it fast, it gets tougher. When I mix it slowly, it gets softer.
Is there any truth to that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, tahini (and cornstarch-water mixtures) are dilatant, non-Newtonian fluids, with viscosity increasing with shear strain. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilatant for definition and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D-wxnID2q4A, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BleCJJAKkgw for demo.

Tahini is much better in hummus than in a swimming pool, though. ;-)